# <ion-item-options> activated by long press

Tags: html, ionic2

I am using *Ionic 2*.

I have a list of items, where I use `<ion-item-options>`. They work perfectly as documented [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/item/ItemSliding/).

When a user slides the `item` to the left, the `options` are exposed.

**Question**

Is it possible to add that when the user long presses on the `item`, it also exposes the `options`?

Thanks

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item-sliding...
        <ion-item...
         .........
        </ion-item>

        <ion-buttons>
          <button light (click)="alert('todo')"><ion-icon class="ion-ios-heart"></ion-icon>Favourite</button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-item-sliding>
  </ion-list>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The longer press (as said by it's name) can be called on by using `(press)` instead of `(click)`. This way you can call a function when the `ion-item` has been pressed and toggle a boolean.

Next in your `ion-item-options` you can set an `*ngIf="yourBoolean"` and your options will be toggled